# SSL Connection to MySQL using SQL Workbench/j

Tags: mysql, security, ssl, rds

I am able to establish RDS/MySQL SSL connection via MySQLWorkbench by specifying the certificate file path but unable to do that via 'SQL Workbench/j' because I couldn't find any option to give the certificate path.

Answer (score 1):

SSL connection feature by specifying certificate path is not available in "SQL Workbench/j". You can make use of another good GUI tool **'Toad for MySQL'** which provides this feature and a descent tool which I'm using from last 7 years.

Comment: We can use any other tool but the question is specific for SQL Workbench/j

Comment: I specified f that as well, there is no such feature in "SQL Workbench/J".

Comment: "Don't waste your time it's not supported" is enormously helpful thanks!